# CSS Checkbox to change content of table cells

Tags: html, css

I have this checkbox in my website that toggles the contents of table cells whenever it is clicked; however, if I place the checkbox in an aside tag, the table in a main tag, and adjust the CSS, it doesn't seem to work properly anymore, what an I doing wrong?

Before(Working):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<table>
    <caption>Table</caption>
    <tr>
        <td data-one="Data One" data-two="Data 2"></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    margin:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    width:10%;
    padding:.5em 0;
    text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after{
    content:"Data 1";
    background:#FCC;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{
    content:"Data 2";
    background:#CCF;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ table td:before{
    content:attr(data-two);
}

td:before{
    display:block;
    content:attr(data-one);
}
```

After(Not Working):

HTML:

```
<aside>
    <input type="checkbox">
</aside>
<main>
    <table>
        <caption>Table</caption>
        <tr>
            <td data-one="Data One" data-two="Data 2"></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    margin:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after{
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
    width:10%;
    padding:.5em 0;
    text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after{
    content:"Data 1";
    background:#FCC;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after{
    content:"Data 2";
    background:#CCF;
}

aside input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ main table td:before{ /*This part is not working*/
    content:attr(data-two);
}

td:before{
    display:block;
    content:attr(data-one);
}
```

Comment: Tested in Chrome and your after mark-up/css is working for me. Which browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the *sibling* selector, what you need should be a *parent* selector, not existent at the moment, in the *CSS Selectors 4 Working Draft* there is instead defined the concept of *[subject of selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)*, so that *aside input[type=checkbox]:checked! ~ main table td:before* should work, but not is available currently by any browser

```
<aside>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <main>
        <table>
            <caption>Table</caption>
            <tr>
                <td data-one="Data One" data-two="Data 2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </main>
</aside>
<main>
    <table>
        <caption>Table</caption>
        <tr>
            <td data-one="Data One" data-two="Data 2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</main>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/CnfFE/

Comment: Oh I see, so the checkbox can't be put into it's own aside tag at the moment. Well its good to hear that this will be possible in the future with CSS4. Also on a side note, I thought self closing tags in HTML5 don't actually work, as in <p/> isn't the same as <p></p>, and that <p/> would actually be the same as <p>. Do they actually work?